# Swift: Gesture in UITableViewCell not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

[My result I want clic ir, its image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aV0Yy.png)

Hello, I want to add a `UIGestureRecognizer` in `UITableViewCell` but it does not work.

Here is my code:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    let recognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan(recognizer:)))
    recognizer.delegate = self
    dragButton.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

func view(post: Post, user: User){
    self.post = post
    self.user = user

    contentLabel.text = post.content
    nameLabel.text = user.userName
}


@objc func handlePan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = recognizer.translation(in: dragButton)

    recognizer.view!.center = CGPoint(x: recognizer.view!.center.x + translation.x, y: recognizer.view!.center.y + translation.y)

    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.containerDragView)
}

override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    if let panGestureRecognizer = gestureRecognizer as? UIPanGestureRecognizer {
        let translation = panGestureRecognizer.translation(in: superview!)
        if fabs(translation.x) > fabs(translation.y) {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
    return false
}
```

It does not work I can not drag my imageview

What should I add for my tableview to execute my gesture?

The final result I want when I slide the right or left button right or left images widens in width

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize GestureRecognizer with a target and action, like so:

```
let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handlePan(_:)))
pan.delegate = self
cell.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
```

Then, you should implement the handler, which will be called each time when a tap event occurs:

```
func handlePan(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
    // handling code
}
```